# Vertical instead of horizontal numbers on x-axis proc univariate

Tags: sas

I am drawing a normal histogram using the proc univariate procedure in sas:

```
proc univariate data=test;
histogram variabel;
run;
```

My question is simple. How do I make SAS write the text on the 1. axis in a vertical and not horizontal way?

I haven't been able to find a proper answer on the forum.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What numbers do you want on the vertical axis exactly?  I can't think of a logical thing to write on the vertical axis for a histogram, other than the percentage (or count) of records in the bins.

Comment: I want to write the text on the 1. axis in a vertical way. Sorry, if it is not clear.

Comment: You're saying you want one character per row, one column?  So it's an issue with fitting, basically?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ODS Graphics, then this is fairly easy:

```
ods graphics off;
axis1 value=(angle=90);
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
histogram age/haxis=axis1;
run;
```

This uses the `axis` options.  These only apply to old-style graphics.

In ODS graphics, this is not really possible in a simple fashion.  Fully, mandatory rotated axis labels are not possible until 9.4, and even then it is in GTL.  You can use annotation to create your own axis labels, though, which is probably your best bet.  Either way you wouldn't do it in `PROC UNIVARIATE` but in a `PROC SGPLOT` histogram.